# Client secret not provided in request error - Keycloak, React, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak, keycloak-services

So I'm fairly new with using Keycloak and I'm using this tutorial to install it with my React & TS app.

https://blog.devgenius.io/security-in-react-and-webapi-in-asp-net-core-c-with-authentification-and-authorization-by-keycloak-89ba14be7e5a

That author says we should set the Access Type to confidential.

I've done the settings he says there (literally the same) and I get

```
{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client secret not provided in request"}
```

my keycloak.json (which is in the public/ folder)

```
{
    "realm": "best-realm",
    "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:28080/auth/",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "best-react",
    "verify-token-audience": true,
    "credentials": {
      "secret": "secret"
    },
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
  }
```

KeycloakService.tsx

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloakInstance = new Keycloak();

/**
 * Initializes Keycloak instance and calls the provided callback function if successfully authenticated.
 *
 * @param onAuthenticatedCallback
 */
const Login = (onAuthenticatedCallback: Function) => {
  keycloakInstance
    .init({ onLoad: "login-required" })
    .then(function (authenticated) {
      authenticated ? onAuthenticatedCallback() : alert("non authenticated");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.dir(e);
      console.log(`keycloak init exception: ${e}`);
    });
};

const KeyCloakService = {
  CallLogin: Login,
};

export default KeyCloakService;
```

Why am I getting this error? I've read some posts that access type confidential doesn't work anymore with a JS adapter. But those posts were older than the posting date of that tutorial (it is written in may 2022). So I don't know what to believe.

Can anybody help me understand this error and teach me how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keycloak.js removed "credential" access type option.

Official comment about this since Keycloak [8.0.0](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/#credentials-support-removed-from-the-javascript-adapter)

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/#credentials-support-removed-from-the-javascript-adapter

You should be use public option in front-end side.
The public option with PCKE(Proof Key for Code Exchange) is protect to steal token that is intended for another app.

[Understanding benefits of PKCE vs. Authorization Code Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767605/understanding-benefits-of-pkce-vs-authorization-code-grant#:%7E:text=The%20PKCE%20does%20protect%20against,and%20that%20PKCE%20mitigates%20against)

This web site shows how to use PCKE from Keycloak

https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/pkce-verification-in-authorization-code-grant/