Why does PKCE exist, when a MITM can intercept the token response?
My understanding of the reason behind PKCE is, if someone was eavesdropping and got to know the authorization code, they wouldn't be able to get an access token without the code verifier.
What's stopping someone from eavesdropping and getting to know the access token?

So if someone intercepts (2) I understand how that's not going to be useful without the code verifier. But what if they intercept (4)? Meaning the Access Token itself from the Auth server to the Browser?

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767605/understanding-benefits-of-pkce-vs-authorization-code-grant

Thank you. That was a good read - in fact I read it twice over. Unfortunately I still do not understand how it answers the question, and I am still confused.
